# if else in pyspark for collapsing column values

Tags: if-statement, dataframe, conditional-statements, pyspark

I am trying a simple code to collapse my categorical variables in dataframe to binary classes after indexing
currently my column has 3 classes- "A","B","C"
I am writing a simple if else statement to collapse classes like

```
def condition(r):
if (r.wo_flag=="SLM" or r.wo_flag=="NON-SLM"):
    r.wo_flag="dispatch" 
else: 
    r.wo_flag="non_dispatch" 
return r.wo_flag 

df_final=df_new.map(lambda x: condition(x))
```

Its not working it doesn't understand the else condition

```
|MData|Recode12|Status|DayOfWeekOfDispatch|MannerOfDispatch|Wo_flag|PlaceOfInjury|Race|
     M|      11|     M|                  4|               7|      C|           99| 1  |    
     M|       8|     D|                  3|               7|      A|           99| 1  |
     F|      10|     W|                  2|               7|      C|           99| 1  |
     M|       9|     D|                  1|               7|      B|           99| 1  |
     M|       8|     D|                  2|               7|      C|           99| 1  |
```

This is the Sample Data

Comment: Are you trying to replace occurrence of 'A' ,'B' with 'dispatch' and 'C' with 'non_dispatch' in wo_flag column ?

Comment: Adding some sample data (what `df` looks like), along with the full error message, will help us to help you.

Comment: @Himaprasoon Yes that is what I want to do I have also attached what DF looks like

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this :

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

def modify_values(r):
    if r == "A" or r =="B":
        return "dispatch"
    else:
        return "non-dispatch"
ol_val = udf(modify_values, StringType())
new_df = df.withColumn("wo_flag",ol_val(df.wo_flag))
```

Things you are doing wrong:

- You are trying to modify Rows (Rows are immmutable)
- When a map operation is done on a dataframe , the resulting data structure is a PipelinedRDD and not a dataframe . You have to apply .toDF() to get dataframe

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer is not very efficient due to the use of a user defined function (UDF).

I think most people are looking for `when`.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import when

matches = df["wo_flag"].isin("SLM", "NON-SLM")
new_df = df.withColumn("wo_flag", when(matches, "dispatch").otherwise("non-dispatch"))
```